# How to release and install two versions of the same android app using the same package on the same device

Tags: android, ant, installation, release, build.xml

I have an android app with two different res folders (res-1, res-2) containing all layout specific and one shared package. Using ant, I can release and install on my device only one of the two versions of the app at a time. What I want is to release and install them both in the same time, in order to be able to see and test them both on my device.
Any suggestions how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to install two apps with the same package name, the existing one will be overwritten with the new installed. Rename the other package would be a solution. Maybe testing one in the AVD and the other one on the device?

Comment: It would be nice to not have duplicate code .. I don't only need to test them but to have them both installed on the device for letting the enduser whether to use one or another

Comment: as @staaar said, what you are trying to do is impossible. The Google Play Store and Android itself requires that every app has a unique package name.

Comment: You could add a preferencelist to choose, layout/ ressource a or ressource b - that wouldn't require to copy the package and keeps the redundant code low. Or release version 'a' with x y ressource and version 'b' with yz ressource.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include all the resources, and then at run time determine which is correct?