# Paid and unpaid app with Android

Tags: android, google-play

Can we use same signing keys for paid and unpaid app, I basically want to push out 2 version free and paid, do I need to do some thing special, thanks.

Comment: 1. use library project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app) to host common code, 2. create two dependent projects for your apps (paid and free), 3. release them separately with unique package names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use same key for all your apps. AFAIK, the only restriction is that you must always use same key that you used on initial publication of an application.

Comment: In fact, you can use the same key for all your applications.

Comment: @EboMike true :) That's what I meant, let me clarify that in answer.

Comment: you misunderstood i have a same app and i need 2 roll out one is free and one is paid can this be done ?, using same package and keys

Comment: @SoftReference then you have two apps (one FREE and one PAID). Make sure that you use unique package name for each of them, sign them with your key, publish. That works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a good reason to *not* use the same key for everything?

Comment: using different package names! can there be a clean way to handle that other then mentioned below 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app

Comment: @SoftRefference sure, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541125/release-several-android-applications-with-same-code-base/3541183#3541183 you need a library project.