# Android/Eclipse: Creating multiple builds with different com identifiers

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app that requires two builds - one is a demo app, the other uses the same codebase but uses a flag to introduce different functionality.

The identifier must be different each time (e.g. com.siteA.appA and com.siteB.appB).

However it doesn't appear to be trivial to use the refactor functionality in Eclipse to change the com identifier - all references change apart from the "import com.siteA.appA.R" reference.

Is there a way to create different builds with different com identifiers/app name within Eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject), look onto [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3541125/272824) for more details.